# Why passing {a, b, c} to a method doesn't work?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, array-initialization

I've tried to pass an initialization list {...} to a constructor and it didn't work.
When I instead declared it in a method local variable (int[]) it worked flawlessly.

Why is that?

```
public class QuickSort {
    int[] a;

    public QuickSort(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ###################
        // ###    WORKS     ##
        // ###################
        int[] a = {8,12,79,12,50,44,8,0,7,289,1};
        QuickSort sort = new QuickSort(a);

        // ###################
        // ### DOESN'T WORK ##
        // ###################
        //QuickSort sort = new QuickSort({8,12,79,12,50,44,8,0,7,289,1});
    }
}
```

Comment: As it happens, what became the varargs language features (as java.util.Arrays.asList) was originally going to do just that. It was probably a mistake to change it...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When declaring an `int[]` and assigning `{1, 2, 3}` the compiler knows you want to create an `int[]` as it's spelled out right there.

In the latter case where you stick the array directly into the method call you would have to use

```
QuickSort sort = new QuickSort(new int[] {8,12,79,12,50,44,8,0,7,289,1});
```

to tell the compiler what your array is.

Answer (score 10):

The `{}` construct is called an array initializer, and it is used to initialize an array in Java. (Reference: [Section 10.6: Array Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6) from [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).)

The reason why passing `{1, 2, 3}` itself is not valid is because there is no type information associated with the initializer.

Therefore, one must let the compiler know the type of the array is by writing `new Type[]`, where the `Type` is the type for which the array is made for.

The following are all valid use of the array initializer:

- `new String[] {"Hello, "World"}`
- `new Character[] {'A', 'B'}`
- `new Runnable[] {new Runnable() {public void run() {}}, new Runnable() {public void run() {}}`

As can be seen, this notation can be used for many data types, so it's not something that is specific for integers.

As for:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
```

The reason why the above is valid is because the type information is provided to the compiler in the variable type declaration, which in this case is `int[]`. What the above is implying is the following:

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

Now, if we have `new int[] {1, 2, 3}`, we are able to create a new `int[]` array in place, so that can be handled as any other `int[]` array would -- it's just that it doesn't have a variable name associated with it.

Therefore, the array created by `new int[] {1, 2, 3}` can be sent into an method or constructor that takes a `int[]` as its argument:

```
new Quicksort(new int[] {1, 2, 3});  // This will work.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because your initialization list has no typing information to it.
Try this:

```
QuickSort sort = new QuickSort(new int[] {8,12,79,12,50,44,8,0,7,289,1});
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can do like this:

```
public class QuickSort {
    int[] a;

    public QuickSort(int ... a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        QuickSort sort = new QuickSort(8,12,79,12,50,44,8,0,7,289,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice ! 
I'll be using this.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't really have type inference. Array variable declarations are a [special case](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6) in the Java language specification, one that does not apply to method parameters. Doing so would be possible, but would add a lot of complexity to the spec, since it would have to handle questions like whether {"a", "b"} creates a String[] or an Object[] - looks obvious here, but what if it's objects in a complex type hierarchy? And what if the method is overloaded and both versions exist?

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces (when used in array literals) may only be used when declaring the array :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried casting the list to int[] before passing it to the constructor?