# Java, most efficient way to pass String array as Method Parameter

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code

```
String[] args = {"a", "b", "c"};
method(args);


private void method(String[] args){
    return args;
}
```

Why can I not do the following without errors?

```
method({"a", "b", "c"});
```

This code is example just to prove the point, not the actual methods I am using. I would like to do the second method instead to clean up my code, and avoid declaring a dozen different arrays when I only use them once to pass to my method.

The heart of the question is what is the most efficient way to pass an array of strings as a method paramter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why passing {a, b, c} to a method doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017486/why-passing-a-b-c-to-a-method-doesnt-work) see also [Java: array initialization syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/java-array-initialization-syntax) and especially [Why array constants can only be used in initializers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10520617/139010)

Comment: Edited question, and redefined goal of answer to be more specifcly about most efficient way to pass array as parameters, provided links do not discuss varargs, therefor question should no longer be considered duplicate.

Comment: Incidentally, your edited question _still_ doesn't mention varargs.

Comment: Solution does... I had never heard of them until answer.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. You're asking *exactly* the same as the duplicate, and the added last sentence IMO doesn't change that at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you want to use varargs.  You don't even need to create an array to sent variable length arguments.

```
String[] strings = method("a", "b", "c");

private String[] method(String... args){
    return args;
}
```

or

```
String[] strings = array("a", "b", "c");

private <T> T[] array(T... args){
    return args;
}
```

or if you want to condense futher

```
String[] strings = array("a, b, c");

private String[] array(String args){
    return args.split(", ?");
}
```

Comment: Are there 3 "." after String because I had 3 Strings?

Comment: And must a varargs parameter be the last parameter of a method? This is curiosity since not covered in original question.

Comment: No, the number of periods has nothing to do with the number of Strings. It's the syntax for varargs. And yes, the varargs parameter needs to be last.

Comment: @djc391 No, there's not three dots because there are three strings. You can pass any number of strings. See [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: What version of Java were Varargs added?

Comment: @djc391 Java 5.0 in 2004.

Comment: Taking this code as answer, over bas's answer because it saves having to write new String[] repeated times(in my case 22 instances)

Comment: @djc391 If you want terse, you can use the third option.

Answer (score 18):

try

```
method(new String[]{ "a", "b", "c"});
```

that way the system knows it is a new string-array.

java is not like php ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you use:

```
method({ "a", "b", "c"});
```

then java has no idea whether you want an array of `String` or of `Object`. You can explicitly tell java what kind of array it is like this:

```
method(new String[] { "a", "b", "c"});
```

That way Java can tell that you mean an array of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a named reference to the array. You can initialize and pass an anonymous array like this:

```
method (new String[]{"a", "b"});
```